# Running Sum that resets to 0 on each new cluster of consecutives

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried and failed to adapt several running sum methods (remember I have to use SQL Server 2008, so it's a bit trickier than in 2012).

The goal is to have a running sum of Amount ordered by Date.  Any time Category field changes value during that list, the sum should restart.

Table structure:

```
[Date], [Category], [Amount]
```

Example:

```
[Date], [Category], [Amount], [RunSumReset]  
-------------------------------------------
1-Jan,  catA,       10,       10
2-Jan,  catA,       5,        15
3-Jan,  catA,       15,       30
15-Jan, catB,       3,        3
1-Feb,  catB,       6,        9
11-Feb, catA,       10,       10
12-Feb, catC,       2,        2
1-Apr,  catA,       5,        5
```

Thanks so much for any slick tips or tricks

Comment: your example, is this sample data or is this expected outcome ? it would be best to post both anyway

Comment: Ya sorry it was a combo of input table and expected output COLUMN (RUNSUMRESET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select sum of amounts in current row and up to first row that has different category. In your case you will need to replace `NULL` with some min date that `SQL Server` supports, like `'17530101'`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      category INT ,
      amount INT ,
      ordering INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1 ),
        ( 1, 2, 2 ),
        ( 1, 3, 3 ),
        ( 2, 4, 4 ),
        ( 2, 5, 5 ),
        ( 3, 6, 6 ),
        ( 1, 7, 7 ),
        ( 1, 8, 8 ),
        ( 4, 9, 9 ),
        ( 1, 10, 10 )

SELECT  category ,
        amount ,
        ( SELECT    SUM(amount)
          FROM      @t
          WHERE     category = t.category
                    AND ordering <= t.ordering
                    AND ordering > ( SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ordering), 0)
                                     FROM   @t
                                     WHERE  category <> t.category
                                            AND ordering < t.ordering
                                   )
        ) AS sum
FROM    @t t
ORDER BY t.ordering
```

Output:

```
category    amount  sum
1           1       1
1           2       3
1           3       6
2           4       4
2           5       9
3           6       6
1           7       7
1           8       15
4           9       9
1           10      10
```

Comment: This worked and ran on full table with no keys in 2 mins.  Not bad.  Performance should only increase with some keys.

Answer (score 2):

Using Version 2008 makes things a bit trickier since the window version of `SUM` with `ORDER BY` clause is not available.

One way to do it is:

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT [Date], Category, Amount,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) - 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Category 
                             ORDER BY [Date]) AS grp
   FROM mytable  
)
SELECT [Date], Category, Amount, Amount + COALESCE(t.s, 0) AS RunSumReset
FROM CTE AS c1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(c2.Amount)
   FROM CTE AS c2
   WHERE c2.[Date] < c1.[Date] AND 
         c1.Category = c2.Category AND 
         c1.grp = c2.grp) AS t(s)
 ORDER BY [Date]
```

The `CTE` is used to calculate field `grp` that identifies islands of consecutive records having the same `Category`. Once `Category` changes, `grp` value also changes. Using this `CTE` we can calculate the running total the way it is normally done in versions prior to `SQL Server 2012`, i.e. using `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: Trying to test this, but the query has been running for 10 mins on a pretty small table. (30k row).

Comment: @user3431083 Any indices on the table?

Comment: The date field that drives the ordering is not the same order as the primary key, so it wouldn't help anyways would it?  I mean no keys are in the query because the query can't benefit from key info because proper results comes from the non key date col which is a dif order than the key

Comment: @user3431083 I think you need to place a non-clustered index on ([Date], Category). Try that and see if it improves performance.